# Android : Time picker get Date in 24 hours Format

Tags: android, timepicker

I am using `Time Picker Toolbar` in my project and I'm facing this problem: getting the time in  Am-Pm Format always returns me the hours in 12h format.

How i can get time in 24 hours Format?

**This is the code I'm using:**

```
TimePicker timePicker=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
int hours= timePicker.getCurrentHour();
```

*e.g if i set time in time picker as 1:00 pm the current code will give me `1`, but i want the output `13`*

Comment: Did you try 1 **pm**?

Comment: Also you should use getHour().

Comment: i am just receiving 1 because it returns an int

Comment: Your question says you picked 1 am, so of course the hour is 1.

Comment: but i want it to be 13 because it is PM

Comment: You should fix the typo in your question.

Comment: You misswrote in the question. Consider looking at my edit please

Comment: Thanks i have done this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Using this trick we can get Hours in 24 Hours Format through Time picker:

**Here is the Code**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        TimePicker timePicker=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);//set Timer to 24 hours Format
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        int hours= timePicker.getCurrentHour();//get Time in 24 Hours using time Picker



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

before using getting current hour.

Comment: Didn't worked 
  TimePicker timePicker=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

        int hours= timePicker.getCurrentHour();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the timepicker to use 24 hour format, use [timepicker.setIs24HourView(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29).

If you want to continue using your format, use a listener:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
      new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, 
      int minute) {
     mHour = hourOfDay;
     mMinute = minute;
    }
};
```

The value `hourOfDay` is **always** 24 hour format.

Hope that helped